# how to - make header span full width and be at the top of the page

Tags: html, css, header

I am trying to use a header tag with a background image and with H1 and H2 tags inside.

The header is not at the top of the page - how do I get it to position at the top?

The header is not filling the full width - how do I get it to fill the full width?

Example: http://www.bobnovell.com/headertest.html

---

I also want to eliminate the blank lines between the H1 and H2. I tried line-height: 0px and it eliminates the space between H1 and H2 but the height of header is reduced such that H1 sticks out above the header and H2 sticks out below the header.

Example: http://www.bobnovell.com/headertest_1.html

---

Another twist - if I define border: 1px solid red, the header is moved closer to the top and the height of the header enough to contain the H1 and H2.

Problem is - I don't want a border on the header.

http://www.bobnovell.com/headertest_2.html (this page may be displaying an older version instead of the current version - some sort of problem with my hosting company. If you see a border around the H1 instead of the header, wait and reload - the problem seems to resolve itself after some undetermined time)

---

But wait, if I set the color of the border to white it eliminates a visible border but there has to be some way to get it to appear correctly without an border defined.

http://www.bobnovell.com/headertest_3.html

Any suggestions?

Bob

Answer (score 0):

These are all margin problems. For example the margin on the top of your H1 tag is causing the space at the top of the page. Adding an inline style will remove that space.

```
<h1 style="margin-top:0px"></h1>
```

margins are also causing your full width problems set your body margins to 0px.

```
<body style="margin:0px"></body>
```

I think you get the idea. You can troubleshoot these issues by right clicking and choosing Inspect Element in Chrome. When you highlight different tags it will show the margins, borders and padding of elements in different colors to give you an idea what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The `header` isn't using the full width because there is a margin or padding on the `body` element. You can remove that:

```
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

(You need to remove both, as some browsers use padding instead of margin for this.)

That will also make your text go all the way out, which is not as pretty, so you would want a margin there:

```
#lipsum { margin: 0 10px; }
```

The reason that the margin of the `h1` and `h2` elements are used outside the `header` element is called [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing). Instead of using a border to prevent it, you can use the `overflow` style:

```
header { overflow: hidden; }
```

Comment: Is there a way to give the header margin:0px padding:0px; other than setting that on the body? I'd rather not have to set margin and padding on  all other elements on the page - what about wrapping the header in a div and setting margin and padding to zero there?   overflow:hidden on the header did the trick.

Comment: Okay - all resolved - set margin and padding on body to 0, set overflow to hidden on header, inserted a div to house the rest of the body (under the header) and set the div left and right margins to 10px, top and bottom margins to 0. Look at http://www.bobnovell.com/headertest_1.html

Comment: @BobN: Yes, that works fine. Note that the margin of the first and last `p` elements are collapsed so that they are used outside the containing `div`, but that's not a problem unless you want to use a background for that too.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS Reset it will solve lots of your problem. http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

h1 {
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
text-transform: none;
text-align: center;
font-size: 50px;
}
h2 {
font-weight: normal;
text-transform: none;
text-align: center;
font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-style: italic;
font-size: 20px
}
header {
 border: 10px #FF0000 solid;
 border-width: 0px;
 background: url("http://www.bobnovell.com/images/white_brick_wall_@2X.png") repeat scroll center top;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<header><!-- style="height: auto">-->
 <h1>H1</h1>
 <h2>H2</h2>
</header><!--</div>-->
<div id="lipsum">
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla laoreet 
 mattis mattis. Cras non lacus turpis. Vivamus auctor erat a tempus gravida. 
 Morbi in porta lacus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus 
 et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Pellentesque sed orci non est volutpat 
 semper vel laoreet magna. Aliquam tempus enim eros, lacinia ultricies massa 
 volutpat non. Integer tristique placerat hendrerit. Vivamus gravida est 
 ante, at varius arcu rhoncus eget. Mauris pretium semper nisl, non viverra 
 risus molestie sit amet. Morbi diam libero, malesuada ac consectetur vel, 
 porta in sem. Aliquam posuere fringilla tortor eget fringilla. Vestibulum 
 condimentum, orci vel varius tincidunt, justo lectus semper metus, non 
 pulvinar eros enim ut elit. </p>
 <p>Sed purus arcu, euismod eu elit vel, tristique scelerisque leo. Curabitur 
 vehicula aliquet ligula sed venenatis. Aliquam euismod euismod cursus. 
 Vestibulum aliquam ut justo et imperdiet. Duis vehicula scelerisque dictum. 
 Donec aliquet leo quis hendrerit condimentum. Aliquam eu sapien nec lacus 
 tempus accumsan vitae at nisi. Mauris arcu urna, commodo vel scelerisque 
 eget, convallis vel elit. Suspendisse sit amet feugiat ex, eu tempus orci.
 </p>
 <p>Vestibulum ultrices vulputate nibh. Nullam sit amet libero vitae diam 
 porta imperdiet. Maecenas et eros at risus mattis dictum eu et quam. 
 Pellentesque vel magna sed orci eleifend ultricies sed eget orci. Nullam 
 pharetra, ligula at egestas ornare, arcu enim volutpat mauris, eu lacinia 
 ante felis nec elit. Fusce ac rutrum nunc, a faucibus dui. Mauris consequat, 
 ante at sollicitudin vestibulum, metus diam placerat felis, sit amet 
 condimentum lectus leo ac orci. Etiam tellus purus, vehicula nec ipsum id, 
 scelerisque efficitur sem. Praesent aliquam neque urna, sed finibus diam 
 placerat sed. Donec tristique tincidunt est, fermentum facilisis tortor. 
 Vestibulum nec nibh vestibulum, semper arcu eget, accumsan sapien. Nulla ac 
 luctus turpis, eu egestas ex. Aliquam sed arcu non dui volutpat maximus sed 
 ac magna. Ut eros neque, faucibus a lacus eu, faucibus tempus ex. Nulla 
 eleifend elit ac lacus gravida condimentum facilisis eu urna. </p>
 <p>Nulla non placerat ante. Quisque ac dui dolor. Duis sit amet risus 
 mauris. Nullam laoreet ipsum sit amet libero consequat, non eleifend dui 
 mollis. Proin ullamcorper, elit auctor auctor vestibulum, magna justo auctor 
 ipsum, eu egestas neque risus eget massa. Nam feugiat tortor ac urna ornare, 
 at egestas enim scelerisque. In efficitur rutrum tellus non scelerisque. 
 Morbi consequat et metus ut finibus. </p>
 <p>Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nam 
 fringilla, massa id molestie dictum, neque ipsum aliquet nisi, pellentesque 
 molestie mauris lectus in ex. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum 
 primis in faucibus. Nullam vitae eros eros. Praesent eget libero sit amet 
 ligula fringilla rutrum vel id quam. Etiam vestibulum condimentum justo, 
 quis luctus lectus tempus ac. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus 
 feugiat pharetra lectus, quis dignissim nunc tincidunt ut. </p>
</div>
```